# Как реализовать автозапуск приложения по рассписанию в бекграунде?

Tags: android, calendar

Необходимо запускать приложение(службу) по рассписанию. Можно без примеров кода хотя если есть туториал было бы не плохо. Главное принцип, что использовать и с чем связывать. А я уже нагуглю. Просто не имею понятия куда копать. Что использовать календарь? Сервисы? Службы какие-то? Приложение должно запускаться не зависимо закрыли его или нет, бутался телефон или нет. Это не активити это сервис который сообщается с сервером(трекер геопозиции). Ничего не законного все по согласованию с пользователем.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаете `Service` с типом `START_STICKY`
2. В сервисе запускаете фоновый `Thread/Runnable`, который по расписанию запрашивает то что вам нужно
3. В сервисе переопределяете метод `onTaskRemoved()`, который сам себе перезапускает (в случае своего же закрытия).

Дальше уже гуглите сами

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от задачи. Начни ознакомление с https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Если нужно прям как будильник - секунда в секунду, то нужен будет AlarmManager.

Если нужно что-то подтянуть с сервера и точность не так нужна, то лучше JobScheduler (есть версия JobSchedulerCompat).